# how to prerender multiple language in angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, prerender

i am using angular universal for server side rendering and  i cant figure out how to prerender multilingual routes

[prerender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmSAt.png)

app being prerender only one language

i tried to wrap whole routing into one lang parametr
like
en/tickets/....

but when i try to prerender

i get result

✔ Prerendering routes to /Users/john/Desktop/project:name/dist/project:name/browser complete.

nothing gets prerendered

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6bbu.png)

angular universal 14.
for translate i am using ngx-translate

Comment: Did you define the proper languages in the angular.json file? Maybe you could add your settings here - it would be easier to figure out what might be wrong

Comment: Are you using the `TranslateJsonLoader` during prerendering? Are you sure that `translateService.use(lang);` is being invoked?

Comment: on the client side changing languages works, but I want to prerender 3 versions of the website